# Why doesn't MUI provide hints for user settings?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, customization, storybook

Trying to customize MUI through **createTheme**, my plans include expanding variants for the Typography component. Added the following custom variants: *'buttonLarge', 'buttonMedium', 'buttonSmall', 'inputLable', 'inputText', 'helperText', 'avatarInitials', 'chip', 'tooltip', 'alertTitle', 'tableHeader', 'badgeLabel', 'toast'.* Following recommendations in MUI documentation for Typography component, I extend the types:

```
import { CSSProperties } from 'react'

import { TypographyVariants } from '@themes/typography/typography.consts'

type CustomVariants = typeof TypographyVariants[number]

declare module '@mui/material/styles' {
  interface TypographyVariants extends Record<CustomVariants, CSSProperties> {}
  interface TypographyVariantsOptions extends Partial<Record<CustomVariants, CSSProperties>> {}
}

declare module '@mui/material/Typography' {
  interface TypographyPropsVariantOverrides extends Record<CustomVariants, true> {}
}
```

Everything is fine, TypeScript now sees them and does not swear, the options are applied correctly, but there is an unpleasant problem. When I try to register an variant, autofill offer only native options, as if there are no custom ones:

[Screen 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Dsv2.png)

It's strange, but if I take a string in curly brackets, then my custom options are there:

[Screen 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yl61N.png)

Please note that if I manually enter a custom version, TS does not swear in both cases, if I make a mistake, it will highlight the error.

Next, StoryBook does not see user variants, only those that are by default:

[Screen 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UaXa6.png)

I checked in PhpStorm and VSCode, passed the project to a friend - the results are the same.

I go to **GitHub** to [write issue](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/40939) on my problem. Developer showed a video where everything works for him, and what is not in the StoryBook, advised him to write there about the current problem. But as an experiment, I created a new CRA + TS + UI project and checked my settings - no changes:

```
<Typography variant='ctrl+space=only_default_variants'>

<Typography variant={'ctrl+space=all_variants'}>
```

That is, it has been proven empirically that the problem is neither in StoryBook nor in Vite.

Dependencies in project:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.3",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.15.10",
    "@mui/material": "^5.15.10",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^7.6.16",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions": "^7.6.16",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^7.6.16",
    "@storybook/addon-themes": "^7.6.16",
    "@storybook/blocks": "^7.6.16",
    "@storybook/react": "^7.6.16",
    "@storybook/react-vite": "^7.6.16",
    "@storybook/test": "^7.6.16",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.56",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.19",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.21.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.21.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint": "^8.56.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^19.0.4",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-typescript": "^17.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.33.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.5",
    "eslint-plugin-simple-import-sort": "^12.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-storybook": "^0.6.15",
    "sass": "^1.71.0",
    "storybook": "^7.6.16",
    "typescript": "^5.3.3",
    "unplugin-fonts": "^1.1.1",
    "vite": "^5.1.3"
  }
```

[GitHub Repository Project](https://github.com/GabbereX/gbx-mui-library)

**Node 20.10.0**

What could be the problem?